# MOD_REWRITE not creating correct path

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, httpd

SO I am trying to setup a RewriteRule on my server for caching static objects.
the files are in this naming scheme /docroot/css/stylesheet.min.css and I have them printed in the code like /docroot/css/stylesheet.min.123438348.css (the number is example it comes from a get modified function). Note docroot is an example directory

how can I have the server ignore the numbers and redirect to the stylesheet.min.css
I need to do this for every css and js files (/js and /css) as well as one specific spritemap image

my current attempt

```
RewriteRule ^/(docroot)/(js|css)/(.+)\.(min)\.(.+)\.(js|css)$ /$1/$2/$3.$4.$6
RewriteRule ^(/docroot/images/spritemap)\.([0-9]+)\.(png)$ $1.$3
```

Update:
Now I have the setup like this

```
<Location />
RewriteEngine on
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(min)\.([0-9]+)\.(js|css)$ $1.$2.$4 [L]
</Location>
```

This is rewriting 
localhost/docroot/css/stylesheet.min.12343242.css
to /var/www/html/docroot/trunk/docroot/css/stylesheet.min.css

so it is getting the right file how do I get apache to take off the beginning of the that the
/var/www/html/docroot/trunk/

---

```
<Location />
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(min)\.([0-9]+)\.(js|css)$ $1.$2.$4 [PT]
</Location>
```

Options FollowSymLinks in Directory listing

---

Ok Now instead of

```
/var/www/html/docroot/trunk/docroot/css/stylesheet.min.css
```

I am getting a url that looks like this

```
/docroot/trunk/docroot/css/stylesheet.min.css
```

I Removed the RewriteBase command
so I still need to remove the beginning /docroot/trunk

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.+min)\.([0-9]+)\.(js|css)$ /$1.$3 [PT]
```

Apache sometimes has unpredictable behaviour when no flag is set. I recommend setting it explicitly every time.
Also, period characters in regexes must be escaped - otherwise they mesn "any character".

I also recommend reading the official Apache docs on mod_rewrite over here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: This doesnt seem to match the url to the file. In my post above that expression matched the file and stripped out the number it just had the full path from filesystem. How do I strip that off too, this did not change anything

Comment: RewriteRule ^.+/(js|css)(.+)\.(min)\.([0-9]+)\.(js|css)$ /docroot/$1$2.$3.$5


This Works

Answer (score 1):

Don't ever use Rewrite directives inside of `<Location>` -- just use them in virtualhost context if you're not using htaccess.  This greatly simplifies every single aspect of using mod_rewrite, and removes the need for stripping of per-directory prefixes,  RewriteBase, etc.